# Java Spring Boot Application Can Not Detect Mongodb Repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to use my mongodb document over MongoRepository in Spring Boot Application for implementing Spring State Machines with Persistence.

The problem is, when I Autowire my MongoRepository class in Spring Application class, it says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3067)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2254)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:755)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance :)

pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemachine-data-mongodb</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

---

Custom MongoRepository:

```
package com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data;

import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data.PaymentDbObject;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface PaymentRepository extends MongoRepository<PaymentDbObject, Integer> {

}
```

---

Application

```
package com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.entity.Events;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.entity.States;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.entity.Payment;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.service.PaymentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.persist.StateMachinePersister;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data.PaymentRepository;
import com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data.PaymentDbObject;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@ComponentScan("com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data")
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.itu.celikelni.spring.boot.statemachine.data")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    @Autowired
    private StateMachinePersister<States, Events, Integer> stateMachinePersister;

    @Autowired
    private PaymentService paymentService;

    @Autowired
    private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;
```

Comment: seem you have dependency problem , try , clean , your project and reinstall it again , also updateProject with force update cheked

Comment: Actually I tried: mvn clean && mvn install && mvn package for many times but no success :(

Comment: so last thing try to delete the `{homeFolder}/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/` and restart you app again

Comment: I whole .m2 folder, run mvn clean & mvn install & mvn compile, and then "Build Artifacts" in IntelliJ editor, but no success again :(

Comment: why adding spring-data-mongodb ? again  remove it from dependcies !

Comment: I removed this dependency bu no success again. The weird thing is, I can succesfully see the related jar file & the interface class (org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository)
under "External Libraries" section that application can not find

Comment: external ?  you should find it under maven deendency !

Comment: I'm new to maven & spring boot framework. I  just deleted the dependency that you mentioned from pom.xml file, if I need to delete this dependency from somewhere else, can you also please state that?

Comment: weird thing ? hmmm , try ceate project step by step by adding dependencies one by one ,

Comment: Removed all dependencies and added 1-by-1 and see all related artifacts under "Maven Dependencies" as mentioned but no success, same exception. By the way, I'm very very appreciate for your help

Comment: no matter @celikelozdinc , that's realy weird , hope you'll find a fix for that , good luck

Answer (score 0):

Let spring boot mongo starter control your spring data mongo dependency version

so `remove` the artifact version of `spring-data-mongodb` from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Here is the correct pom.xml file which I can succesfully import MongoRepository interface.

Just removed version information from spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb artifact

   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>

Comment: yes, finally, it is solved when I remove version information from spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb artifact.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That s Great. =).